# PhantomJS Body text spills into page header

Tags: c#, html, pdf, phantomjs

I am running into an issue with PhantomJS making a snapshot of a C# MVC view into a pdf.

Currently, when the code runs, I call the PhantomJS C# wrapper and points it to a view, which is generated and the PhantomJS does whatever it does and converts it to a PDF file. That's fine and dandy.

However, when I look at the PDF file, I see this bit:

[image]

As you can see, the "Feedback Report Table Of Contents" is in the page header. Ideally, it would be best if the header would have it's own space in the DOM and everything else would be pushed down.

Here's the rasterize.js file that I had to modify:

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
address, output, size, pageWidth, pageHeight, fullName;

if (system.args.length < 3 || system.args.length > 5) {
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    fullName = system.args[3];    
    page.viewportSize = { width: 1140, height: 1000 };
    page.paperSize =
    {
        height: '11in',
        width: '8.5in',
        margin: {
            top: '20px',
            bottom: '20px',
            left: '10px',
            right: '10px'
        },
        header: {
            height: '20px',
            contents: phantom.callback(function () {
                return "<div style='border-bottom: 1px solid #808080; margin-top: -10px;'>" +
                        "<span style='color: #808080; font-size: 12px;'>Virtual Competency Assessment - Feedback Report</span><br />" +
                        "<span style='color: #808080; font-size: 12px;'>" + "John Doe" + " - " + GetDate() + "</span>" +
                   "</div>";
            })
        },
        footer: {
            height: '20px',
            contents: phantom.callback(function (pageNum, numPages) {
                return "<div style='text-align: center;'>" +
                        "<span style='color: #808080; font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial;'>" +
                            "Page <strong>" + pageNum + "</strong> of <strong>" + numPages + "</strong>" + 
                        "</span>" +
                    "</div>";
            })
        }
    };
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit(1);
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                page.render(output);
                phantom.exit();
            }, 200);
        }
    });
}

var GetDate = function () {
    var today = new Date();

    return (today.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + today.getDate() + "/" + today.getFullYear();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you very much for your time.

Jason

Comment: I'm going to mark this as close as I do not need the answer anymore. I used CSS to manually make sure the previous page content didn't run into the header. Thank you.